# Puppeteer full page screenshot, getting extra white space rendered at bottom of page

Tags: screenshot, puppeteer

I'm playing with **Puppeteer v1.3.0** to generate some screenshots at various breakpoints during build/deploy.  I don't seem to understand how to generate a full page screenshot properly.

I can get a full page screenshot exactly as I want it, **but I have to set the viewport dimensions twice** which seems very odd to me (I just set an arbitrary height, then evaluate the clientHeight):

```
//xl
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1201,
    height: 600
});
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1201,
    height: await page.evaluate(() => document.body.clientHeight),
    isMobile: true //whether the meta viewport tag is taken into account
});
await page.screenshot({path: 'xl.png');
```

I've tried setting waitUntil networkidle, just evaluating the clientHeight and setting fullPage to true in the page.screenshot:

```
await page.goto('my-url-here', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
});
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1201,
    height: await page.evaluate(() => document.body.clientHeight),
    isMobile: true //whether the meta viewport tag is taken into account
});
await page.screenshot({path: 'arrowdental_xl.png', fullPage: true});
```

And I get a full page screenshot, but **there's a bunch of extra white space at the bottom**, which I don't want.

What's the proper way to get a full page screenshot in Puppeteer?  Again, the first method above works, but it feels dumb I have to set the viewport dimensions twice. I'd like to have cleaner code, if possible.

Comment: Not sure if is the solution, but could you please put first your `page.setViewport` before the `page.goto`. In my case seems that my site isn't response using Chromium.

Comment: Also test putting an argument on lunch: `await puppeteer.launch(["--start-maximized"]);`

Comment: Did you try setting viewport to page height?

Comment: This seems to only happen for me when I launch Puppeteer in headless mode. If I run it head-full there is not white bottom border...

Answer (score -1):

With puppeteer sharp v 1.11.2

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
});
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync("https://www.google.com/");
await page.ScreenshotAsync(@"c:\temp\google.png", new ScreenshotOptions {FullPage = true});
```

so passing ScreenshotOptions.FullPage to ScreenshotAsync()